# pyarrow read_csv with different amount of columns per row

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pyarrow

My CSV file contains 14 million rows and has a variable amount of columns. The first 27 columns will always be available, and a row can have up to 16 more columns for a total of 43.

Using vanilla pandas I've found this workaround:

```
largest_column_count = 0
with open(data_file, 'r') as temp_f:
    lines = temp_f.readlines()
    for l in lines:
        column_count = len(l.split(',')) + 1
        largest_column_count = column_count if largest_column_count < column_count else largest_column_count
temp_f.close()

column_names = [i for i in range(0, largest_column_count)]
all_columns_df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, delimiter=',', names=column_names, dtype='category').replace(pd.np.nan, '', regex=True)
```

This will create the table with all my data plus empty cells where the data is not available. 
With a smaller file, this works perfectly well. With the complete file, my memory usage goes over the roof.

I've been reading about Apache Arrow and, after a few attempts to load a structured csv file (same amount of columns for every row), I'm extremely impressed.
I've tried to load my data file, using the same concept as above:

```
fixed_column_names = [str(i) for i in range(0, 27)]
extra_column_names = [str(i) for i in range(len(fixed_column_names), largest_column_count)]

total_columns = fixed_column_names
total_columns.extend(extra_column_names)

read_options = csv.ReadOptions(column_names=total_columns)
convert_options = csv.ConvertOptions(include_columns=total_columns,
                                     include_missing_columns=True,
                                     strings_can_be_null=True)

table = csv.read_csv(edr_filename, read_options=read_options, convert_options=convert_options)
```

but I get the following error

***Exception: CSV parse error: Expected 43 columns, got 32***

I need to use the csv provided by pyarrow, if not I wouldn't be able to create the pyarrow table to then convert to pandas

`from pyarrow import csv`

Has anybody come across the same issue and can help me?

**Edit:**

Fixed the second code block

Comment: It isn't clear what remainder_column_names contains, but I think it might be being used incorrectly here.  I believe pyarrow will expect one 1 entry per row per value in column_names.  The include_column_names parameter is used for reducing the amount of data parsed/returned and adding placeholders if there is a value in include_column_names that isn't it column_names.  I don't believe that parsing a variable number of columns  is supported.  You might consider opening a feature request JIRA (https://issues.apache.org/) or discussing it on the mailing list.

Comment: Oh yeah.. I've copied the code from a previous experiment, the remainder_column_names should be column_names. I had a list with the fixed column names and a list the extend column name.
Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: I tangled with the problem of a malformed csv which was too big to load into memory and wrote about some possible solutions here. https://redwallanalytics.com/2022/04/21/loading-a-large-messy-csv-using-data-table-fread-with-cli-tools/